# jQuery based three dots drop-down not working for loop in Laravel

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

I have multiple Bootstrap cards displaying inside for loop where I wanted to offer 3 dots menu option to users. My script is working but the code for menu is working for only first card not for all of the cards.

How would I customize my script to let it work for all of the cards in loop?

Blade

```
       @if (count($data)>0)
         @foreach ($data as $row)
    
              <div class="three-buttons">
              <div class="card-title mb-0 h5 font-weight-bold dark-color">{{$row->car_title}}</div>
                 <div>
                  <div class="more">
                   <button id="more-btn" class="more-btn">
                   <span class="more-dot"></span>
                   <span class="more-dot"></span>
                   <span class="more-dot"></span>
                  </button>
                  
                  <div class="more-menu">
                   <div class="more-menu-caret">
                   <div class="more-menu-caret-outer"></div>
                   <div class="more-menu-caret-inner"></div>
                   </div>
                  
              <ul class="more-menu-items" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="more-btn" aria-hidden="true">
                <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation">
                <button type="button" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem">Share</button>
                </li>
                </ul>
               </div>
               </div>
               </div> 
    
    @endforeach

@endif
```

Javascript

```
var el = document.querySelector('.more');
var my_btn = el.querySelector('.more-btn');
var menu = el.querySelector('.more-menu');
var visible = false;

function showMenu(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!visible) {
        visible = true;
        el.classList.add('show-more-menu');
        menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu, false);
    }
}

function hideMenu(e) {
    if (my_btn.contains(e.target)) {
        return;
    }
    if (visible) {
        visible = false;
        el.classList.remove('show-more-menu');
        menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
        document.removeEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu);
    }
}
my_btn.addEventListener('click', showMenu, false);
```

CSS

```
    .more-menu {
        width: 100px;
    }

    /* More Button / Dropdown Menu */

    .more-btn,
    .more-menu-btn {
        background: none;
        border: 0 none;
        line-height: normal;
        overflow: visible;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: -20px;
    }

    .more-dot {
        background-color: #020b56;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }

    .more-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8%;
        z-index: 900;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-top: 9px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccd8e0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(0, 15px) scale(.95);
        transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .more-menu-caret {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: 12px;
        width: 18px;
        height: 10px;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-outer,
    .more-menu-caret-inner {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: -1px;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-outer {
        border-bottom: 10px solid #c1d0da;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: auto;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-inner {
        top: 1px;
        left: 1px;
        border-left: 9px solid transparent;
        border-right: 9px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
    }

    .more-menu-items {
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .more-menu-item {
        display: block;
    }

    .more-menu-btn {
        min-width: 100%;
        color: #66757f;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .more-menu-item:hover {
        background-color: #489fe5;
    }

    .more-menu-item:hover .more-menu-btn {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .more-btn:hover .more-dot,
    .show-more-menu .more-dot {
        background-color: #516471;
    }

    .show-more-menu .more-menu {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `<div id="three-buttons">` in each iteration resulting in many divs with same id.  The click only affects the first element with that div.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.more');
var my_btn = el.querySelector('.more-btn');
var menu = el.querySelector('.more-menu');
var visible = false;

function showMenu(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!visible) {
    visible = true;
    el.classList.add('show-more-menu');
    menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu, false);
  }
}

function hideMenu(e) {
  if (my_btn.contains(e.target)) {
    return;
  }
  if (visible) {
    visible = false;
    el.classList.remove('show-more-menu');
    menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu);
  }
}
my_btn.addEventListener('click', showMenu, false);
```

```css
.more-menu {
        width: 100px;
    }

    /* More Button / Dropdown Menu */

    .more-btn,
    .more-menu-btn {
        background: none;
        border: 0 none;
        line-height: normal;
        overflow: visible;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: -20px;
    }

    .more-dot {
        background-color: #020b56;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }

    .more-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8%;
        z-index: 900;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-top: 9px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccd8e0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(0, 15px) scale(.95);
        transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .more-menu-caret {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: 12px;
        width: 18px;
        height: 10px;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-outer,
    .more-menu-caret-inner {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: -1px;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-outer {
        border-bottom: 10px solid #c1d0da;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: auto;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-inner {
        top: 1px;
        left: 1px;
        border-left: 9px solid transparent;
        border-right: 9px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
    }

    .more-menu-items {
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .more-menu-item {
        display: block;
    }

    .more-menu-btn {
        min-width: 100%;
        color: #66757f;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .more-menu-item:hover {
        background-color: #489fe5;
    }

    .more-menu-item:hover .more-menu-btn {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .more-btn:hover .more-dot,
    .show-more-menu .more-dot {
        background-color: #516471;
    }

    .show-more-menu .more-menu {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="three-buttons">
    <div class="card-title mb-0 h5 font-weight-bold dark-color">car title 1</div>
    <div>
      <div class="more">
        <button id="more-btn" class="more-btn">
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                      </button>

        <div class="more-menu">
          <div class="more-menu-caret">
            <div class="more-menu-caret-outer"></div>
            <div class="more-menu-caret-inner"></div>
          </div>

          <ul class="more-menu-items" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="more-btn" aria-hidden="true">
            <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation">
              <button type="button" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem">Share</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-title mb-0 h5 font-weight-bold dark-color">car title 2</div>
      <div>
        <div class="more">
          <button id="more-btn" class="more-btn">
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                      </button>

          <div class="more-menu">
            <div class="more-menu-caret">
              <div class="more-menu-caret-outer"></div>
              <div class="more-menu-caret-inner"></div>
            </div>

            <ul class="more-menu-items" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="more-btn" aria-hidden="true">
              <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation">
                <button type="button" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem">Share</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Mall How can I update the Id for each iteration please?

Comment: @Shaan - I don't see where you access `#three-buttons` in your code so it's hard to say.

Comment: I' m not using #three-buttons anywhere but using the same script that I shared in above question. Could you recommend where and how should I adjust my script ?

Comment: Change to `<div class="three-buttons">` temporarily to see if that helps.

Comment: Nothing happened. :(

Comment: Then my answer does not fix your issue. You should still fix `<div id="three-buttons">` though. Maybe delete that div if it serves no purpose. Otherwise leave as `<div class="three-buttons">`. If you do make a change please edit your question to show the updated code.

Comment: I just updated my question and added class as per your recommendation.

Comment: @Shaan I added a snippet that attempts to reproduce your issue. Please check it. Is there some local css that needs to be applied that maybe you could add to your question? And what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I just updated my question and add required CSS code. Please have a look. Moreover I' m using Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `document.body.addEventListener('click', showMenu);` event listener to listen a clicked event. In the `showMenu(e)` function I added `if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && e.target.classList.contains("more-btn"))` to check if the clicked event is a button and has a class of "more-btn". But I'm not sure about the positioning of your pop-up menu (css to be exact) because when you click either button it appears in the same position

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.more');
var my_btn = el.querySelector('.more-btn');
var menu = el.querySelector('.more-menu');
var visible = false;

function showMenu(e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON" && 
   e.target.classList.contains("more-btn")) {
    if (!visible) {
    visible = true;
    el.classList.add('show-more-menu');
    menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu, false);
  }
}
  
}

function hideMenu(e) {
  if (my_btn.contains(e.target)) {
    return;
  }
  if (visible) {
    visible = false;
    el.classList.remove('show-more-menu');
    menu.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', hideMenu);
  }
}
document.body.addEventListener('click', showMenu);
```

```css
.more-menu {
        width: 100px;
    }

    /* More Button / Dropdown Menu */

    .more-btn,
    .more-menu-btn {
        background: none;
        border: 0 none;
        line-height: normal;
        overflow: visible;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-left: -20px;
    }

    .more-dot {
        background-color: #020b56;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 4px;
        height: 4px;
        margin-left: 1px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        transition: background-color 0.3s;
    }

    .more-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8%;
        z-index: 900;
        float: left;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin-top: 9px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccd8e0;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(0, 15px) scale(.95);
        transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .more-menu-caret {
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        left: 12px;
        width: 18px;
        height: 10px;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-outer,
    .more-menu-caret-inner {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: -1px;
        font-size: 0;
        line-height: 1;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-outer {
        border-bottom: 10px solid #c1d0da;
        border-left: 10px solid transparent;
        border-right: 10px solid transparent;
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: auto;
    }

    .more-menu-caret-inner {
        top: 1px;
        left: 1px;
        border-left: 9px solid transparent;
        border-right: 9px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
    }

    .more-menu-items {
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .more-menu-item {
        display: block;
    }

    .more-menu-btn {
        min-width: 100%;
        color: #66757f;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        position: relative;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .more-menu-item:hover {
        background-color: #489fe5;
    }

    .more-menu-item:hover .more-menu-btn {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .more-btn:hover .more-dot,
    .show-more-menu .more-dot {
        background-color: #516471;
    }

    .show-more-menu .more-menu {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1);
        pointer-events: auto;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="three-buttons">
    <div class="card-title mb-0 h5 font-weight-bold dark-color">car title 1</div>
    <div>
      <div class="more">
        <button id="more-btn" class="more-btn">
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                      </button>

        <div class="more-menu">
          <div class="more-menu-caret">
            <div class="more-menu-caret-outer"></div>
            <div class="more-menu-caret-inner"></div>
          </div>

          <ul class="more-menu-items" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="more-btn" aria-hidden="true">
            <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation">
              <button type="button" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem">Share</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
<br /><br />
      <div class="card-title mb-0 h5 font-weight-bold dark-color">car title 2</div>
      <div>
        <div class="more">
          <button id="more-btn" class="more-btn">
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                       <span class="more-dot"></span>
                      </button>

          <div class="more-menu">
            <div class="more-menu-caret">
              <div class="more-menu-caret-outer"></div>
              <div class="more-menu-caret-inner"></div>
            </div>

            <ul class="more-menu-items" tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="more-btn" aria-hidden="true">
              <li class="more-menu-item" role="presentation">
                <button type="button" class="more-menu-btn" role="menuitem">Share</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```